# Pdf resolution scaling for plotting

Tags: c++, c, pdf, visual-c++, ofstream

I am trying to create a pdf file where I draw a graph from a set of points, 2000+ points. The width of the pdf is set to 612. I want to be able to plot all the points in one line. I am currently drawing at a scale of 1 to 1, one point per pixel. How can I scale my drawing so I can draw all 2000+ points.

Comment: How are you creating the pdf? Do you use some library, or do you manually generate it, just using `ofstream`?

Comment: @chtz- im using this http://www.vulcanware.com/cpp_pdf/index.html#pdfs