# Show more points then resolution

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, fopen, iostream

I am drawing a graph with 2000+ points to a pdf file. The resolution of the pdf is 612 x 792.  I can only draw 612 points to the pdf because the width is 612. I am mapping 1 point to 1 pixel. How can I plot all 2000+ samples to the pdf. I am using this lib  http://www.vulcanware.com/cpp_pdf/index.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pdf resolution scaling for plotting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301673/pdf-resolution-scaling-for-plotting)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Scale the points, using `x = (x * 612) / 2000`. This will mean that if 2 points are close to each other (including "similar y") they will overwrite each other.

Option 2: Treat each point as a square; and calculate floating point values for the "left edge x" and "right edge x" that have been scaled (`left_x = ( (x-width/2.0) * 612.0) / 2000.0; right_x = ( (x+width/2.0) * 612.0) / 2000.0;`), and draw the square using anti-aliasing, by calculating "area of destination pixel that the square overlaps" for each destination pixel that overlaps with the square. In this case you will need to do "dest_pixel = max(dest_pixel + area, 1);" to clamp pixel values when squares overlap.

Option 3: Rotate the whole thing 90 degrees so that "x axis" goes vertically down the page (and can be split across multiple pages if necessary); and if this causes a problem for y then use one of the options above for y.

Note that "option 2" can be done in both (vertical and horizontal) directions at the same time. To do this, start by determining the edges of the square, like:

```
    left_x = point_x / MAX_SRC_X * MAX_DEST_X;
    right_x = (point_x + 1) / MAX_SRC_X * MAX_DEST_X;
    top_y = point_y / MAX_SRC_Y * MAX_DEST_Y;
    bottom_y = (point_y + 1) / MAX_SRC_Y * MAX_DEST_Y;
```

Then have a "for each row that is effected" loop that calculates how much each row is effected, like:

```
    for(int y = top_y; y < bottom_y; y++) {
        row_top = fmax(y, top_y);
        row_bottom = fmin(y+1, bottom_y);
        row_weight = row_bottom - row_top;
```

Then have a similar "for each column that is effected" loop, like:

```
        for(int x = left_x; x < right_x; x++) {
            column_left = fmax(x, left_x);
            column_right = fmin(x+1, right_x);
            column_weight = column_right - column_left;
```

Then calculate the area for the pixel, set the pixel, and complete the loops:

```
            dest_pixel_area = row_weight * column_weight;
            pixel[y][x].red = min(pixel[y][x].red + dest_pixel_area * red, MAX_RED);
            pixel[y][x].green = min(pixel[y][x].green + dest_pixel_area * green, MAX_GREEN);
            pixel[y][x].blue = min(pixel[y][x].blue + dest_pixel_area * blue, MAX_BLUE);
        }
    }
```

*Note: All code above is untested and simplified. It can be faster to break the loops up into "first line/column; loop for middle area only; then last line/column" to remove most of the `fmin`/`fmax`.*

If you only need to do this in one direction, delete the parts for the direction you don't need and use `1.0` for the corresponding `row_weight` or `column_weight`.

Comment: @Brendan-  I tried the first option, its able to draw all the points but it distorts that plot. The plot isn't smooth. I'm not not sure how to implement option 2.